# Password protect website

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I'm trying to password protect my website from ONE ip address. 
I just want to restrict an ip from accessing my website, but still allow them to access it if they have the password.

My current code .htaccess

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "Login" 
AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd 
Require valid-user 
Order deny,allow 
Deny from 1.1.1.1 
Allow from all 
Satisfy any
```

It doesn't work, I'm not sure why.

Comment: First and foremost, you need to expand on the statement "It doesn't work."

Comment: When accessing from the IP address, it doesn't ask for a login

Comment: put some rubbish in that file then try and load that particular page. Put something like blabla at the authtype bit. Does the page load without errors?

Comment: @Peter I believe the .htaccess file is not being loaded :)

Comment: Still nothing. I'm not sure what's happening. How do you make sure a .htaccess is being loaded